# How do I source install development headers?

Tags: macos, unix, installation

I'm installing on Unix/OSX software called Julius which states this:

"To compile with [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) support, first install the development files (headers) of libsndfile, and compile Julius from the source"

But I have idea how to install the headers. It does indeed install fine with .configure, make, make install but I guess there is an extra step for the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your distribution might provide a `linsndfile-dev` package or similar (the [Julius](http://jaist.dl.sourceforge.jp/julius/47534/Juliusbook-4.1.5.pdf) manual has some examples in section 2.4.1) and that's probably the easiest method.

Otherwise, install `libsndfile` first:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

then compile **Julius** as you did and it should work. If you want to double-check, the `./configure` output for Julius should, at some point, talk about `libsndfile`if it detects it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the headers come with the library, so the first place you should look is wherever you got your install of libsndfile from. If you *haven't* installed libsndfile yet, then that would be where you start.

Comment: There are various directories (such as src) with various files (including h files), but I still don't know what to do with them.